# Lyx: reduce width full screen

Tags: lyx

How the hell does one reduce width in fullscreen mode in the lastest version of Lyx? (Lyx 2.2.3) There is no option anywhere (it used to be: Tools > Prefs > Editing > Control > Fullscreen > Limit text width).

Fullscreen Lyx is one of its best features but trying to write a document where text spans the entire screen is impossible.

MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just tested on LyX 2.2.2, 2.2.x, and 2.3.0beta1, and it works well here on Ubuntu. What OS are you using? The option doesn't even show up? Can you give a screenshot of the options that show on that page? Which LyX version + OS did it work correctly for you?

Comment: @scottkosty added screenshots. worked on current OS with previous version, though I don't remember which version exactly.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot under Editing > Control? (and thanks for your edits with info about OS)

Comment: @scottkosty that did it: Editing > Control then selecting "Limit text width". Why isn't this in the wiki page? Searching help didn't work either. Thanks!

Comment: Glad we figured it out. I put an answer that I think solves the confusion. As for the Wiki, feel free to add it (you can edit it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to preferences, then Editing > Control > Fullscreen > Limit text width.

I believe that the confusion comes from the instructions that say to access preferences in the tools menu. This is only true on Linux and Windows. On Macintosh, the preferences are accessed from the "LyX" menu. I believe this is done because that's the convention on Mac.