# Lyx: add margins to the input editor (not TeX output)

Tags: lyx

I would like to display the LyX text editor/interpreter with some margins, as using a large screen makes the text very widespread and hard to read. Note that this is only about the text editor, not the TeX output itself.

Is this possible in Lyx?

Comment: If the answer answered your question can you accept it to get it out of the unanswered queue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fortunately, you can. You have a detailed answer here:
[Lyx: reduce width full screen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394411/lyx-reduce-width-full-screen)

On my screen (in French, but the order should be the same), with LyX on OSX, it is the last line and then you can insert a text width, in pixels. 900 is fine with me on a 27' iMac.

One caveat: this only works in Fullscreen mode.

[image: Screen capture from Lyx's preferences on OSX],

Comment: Merci Mathias! I think the answer is then: "use the fullscreen mode", and eventually change its width. I never used that mode, not sure what its relevance is, but at least it allows me to change the display width, nice!